# Slow serialization in django rest framework

Tags: django, optimization, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to figure out why django rest framework's `ModelSerializer` is so slow. I'm aware of the problem with N+1 queries, it's not the case. I have a super simple model that has only numbers and strings. Profiling shows that my code spends most of the time inside `Serializer::to_representation()` method which does not make any database queries.

The weird thing is that time spent inside `to_representation` method is sometimes `0.00001s` (which is around what I would expect), sometimes `0.001s` and sometimes (very rarely) `0.05s`. The time does not correlate with the size of the object being serialized (they are all around the same size in my case).

Serialization of 300 objects takes around `1s`. My hand-written serializer which simply writes an `obj` to json string getting all fields manually instead of `MySerializer(obj).data` does the job in `0.05s` which is comparable to what I would expect given `0.00001s` spent inside `to_representation`.

What may cause `to_representation` method work so slowly sometimes and how can I make my serializer faster?

Comment: Did you find any solution?